# GroovyWS broken?

Tags: soap, groovy, client, groovyws

i'm trying to implement a SOAP webservice-client for a IIS-WS-Endpoint.

My client-language is groovy.
I tried the following example: http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS

But somehow the grape seems to be broken. When i run `grape -V install org.codehaus.groovy.modules groovyws` it gives me some errors which seem to be the result of unresolved dependencies.

This is the console-output:
    :: problems summary ::
    :::: WARNINGS
                    [NOT FOUND  ] org.springframework#spring-core;2.5.6!spring-core.jar (3ms)

```
        ==== localm2: tried

          file:C:\Users\username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/2.5.6/spring-core-2.5.6.jar

                [NOT FOUND  ] org.springframework#spring-context;2.5.6!spring-context.jar (1ms)

        ==== localm2: tried

          file:C:\Users\username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/2.5.6/spring-context-2.5.6.jar

                [NOT FOUND  ] org.springframework#spring-web;2.5.6!spring-web.jar (0ms)

        ==== localm2: tried

          file:C:\Users\username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/2.5.6/spring-web-2.5.6.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

Any suggestions?
Or maybe tutorials for using CXF with Groovy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... After reading http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS again more carefuly found out, it clearly says "Make sure to have the correct GroovyWS grape config file" which is described [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS+grape+config+file).

Now it works.